# teradata: when to use primary index for querying table?

Tags: indexing, teradata

i created a join index on single table, when i query the table with where clause, one with "=", and the other with "%", but seems the first query use primary index, and the second query do not use it, don't understand, the two query on the primary index column, why the second query do not use primary index ?

the join index on single table is as follows:

```
CREATE JOIN INDEX CustomerService.EMP_JI AS
SELECT employee_number ,
       department_number,
       employee.last_name,
       manager_employee_number
FROM customerservice.employee
PRIMARY INDEX ( last_name );
```

the first explain,

```
explain sel * from customerservice.employee where last_name = 'tony';


1) First, we do a single-AMP RETRIEVE step from
 CustomerService.EMP_JI by way of the primary index
 "CustomerService.EMP_JI.last_name = 'tony '" with no residual
 conditions into Spool 2 (group_amps), which is redistributed by
 the hash code of (CustomerService.EMP_JI.employee_number) to few
 AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 2 by row hash.  The size
 of Spool 2 is estimated with low confidence to be 1 row (45 bytes).
 The estimated time for this step is 0.01 seconds.
 2) Next, we do a group-AMPs JOIN step from customerservice.employee
 by way of a RowHash match scan with no residual conditions, which
 is joined to Spool 2 (Last Use) by way of a RowHash match scan.
 customerservice.employee and Spool 2 are joined using a merge join,
 with a join condition of ("Field_1025 =
 customerservice.employee.employee_number").  The result goes into
 Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally on that AMP.  The
 size of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 1 row (143
 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.03 seconds.
 3) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
 in processing the request.
 -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
 statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.04 seconds.
```

the second explain,

```
explain sel * from customerservice.employee where last_name like '%tony';


1) First, we lock a distinct customerservice."pseudo table" for read
 on a RowHash to prevent global deadlock for
 customerservice.employee.
2) Next, we lock customerservice.employee for read.
3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from customerservice.employee by
 way of an all-rows scan with a condition of (
 "customerservice.employee.last_name LIKE '%tony'") into Spool 1
 (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of
 Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 2 rows (286 bytes).
 The estimated time for this step is 0.07 seconds.
4) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
 in processing the request.
-> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
 statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.07 seconds.
```

Comment: To your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50185646/3776858): This might help: `awk '{print $1,$2}' file`

Answer (score 1):

where clause needs to have equality condition(=) for accessing primary index because primary index distributes the rows on hashing value of primary index.

[Teradata Optimizer Equal vs Like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712177/teradata-optimizer-equal-vs-like-in-sql)

Comment: yes, it is a duplicate of the post mentioned,